# How to limit row insertion in a recursive trigger using SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

First of all I am querying directly in a SQLite database managment software. Therefore, any use of programming language is impossible in my case and my only option is to work with triggers.

My database has a table named **Article** that I would like to populate with **n** dummy objects for test purpposes without reaching the recursive limit of triggers(limit I am unable to change since I would have to recompile the database). I suppose, by reading the official documentation, that this limit is fixed to 500 by default.

So far I have created a functionnal trigger but I am unable to stop its recursion after **n** insertion:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER 'myTrigger' 
AFTER INSERT ON 'Article' 
WHEN (insertedRowNumber < 500) 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO Article(...) VALUES(...); 
END;
```

The **Article** table structure doesn't contain any kind of timestamp and it can not be changed because the database is already deployed for production.

How would one limit the number of rows inserted with the trigger pattern I provided ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can limit entries in `Article` instead of number of insertions, just:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger AFTER INSERT ON Article WHEN ((SELECT COUNT() FROM Article)<500) BEGIN INSERT INTO Article(...) VALUES(...); END;
```

Another option is using a helper view:

```
CREATE VIEW hlpArticle(a, ..., z, hlpCnt) AS SELECT a, ..., z, 1 AS hlpCnt FROM Article;
CREATE TRIGGER hlpTrigger INSTEAD OF INSERT ON hlpArticle WHEN (NEW.hlpCnt>0) BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Article(a, ..., z) VALUES(NEW.a, ..., NEW.z);
    INSERT INTO hlpArticle(a, ..., z) VALUES(NEW.a, ..., NEW.z, NEW.hlpCnt-1);
END;
```

So when you do:

```
INSERT INTO hlpArticle(a, ..., z, hlpCnt) VALUES('val_a', ..., 'val_z', 500);
```

it will insert 500 records on `Article`.

Comment: Hey thank you for your quick answer but I have one question: isn't the view created definitely ? Or will it be updated each time my trigger is called ? I am asking thatbecause I would like to insert 100000+ dummy rows in the Article table and my only solution is to execute (100000/500) times my triggers to populate this database.

Comment: View has no data. In this case is just a query on `Article` - but it is just a workaround to be able to use a trigger `INSTEAD OF`. Extra column `hlpCnt` is decremented in each call to trigger, until reach zero, so we can control how many inserts we want to do in real table `Article`.